# TFS2013 Merge Collections

Tags: tfs

We have a TFS 2013 on-premises server that we just migrated over from VSO for a customer. They originally had 2 VSO accounts. Each account had a collection of projects. They have now been attached to the TFS thereby creating 2 collections that we can see & browse successfully. They'd like to merge all of the projects into one collection while maintaining all history info, etc... Is this possible?  **We are NOT trying to merge projects...ONLY the collections.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for merging Collections is exactly the same as the process for merging Team Projects. You would pick one collection to keep and create a new Team Project for each of the Team Project that you want to migrate from the other collection. You would then use the TFS Integration Platform to push the data across...

I know this is not what you want to hear but it is the only possible way to achieve this.

Comment: Would this keep all of the history, etc?  Would we lose ANYTHING?

Comment: The changesets will loose user their user and date. The information is preserved - kind of - by adding the user and date to the checkin-comment, but it's not as comfortable to search for as before. Not sure about work items etc.